# Why this type of nesting is not possible in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool cmp(pair<string, int> aa, pair<string, int> bb) {
    return (aa.second == bb.second ? aa.first < bb.first : aa.second > bb.second);
}

int32_t main() {
     map<string, set<pair<string, int>, decltype(cmp)>> store;
}
```

I was trying to make this type of container but it is showing error. Can someone please tell me why maps can't store like this?

The following error was generated while I tried to compile the above code.

```
Exit code: 1 Errors while compiling:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\map:60,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:81,
                 from c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\CP\C_Largest_Subsequence.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_tree.h: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Rb_tree_key_compare<bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)>':
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_tree.h:660:9:   required from 'struct std::_Rb_tree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::_Identity<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>), std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >::_Rb_tree_impl<bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>), false>'
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_tree.h:706:31:   required from 'class std::_Rb_tree<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::_Identity<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>), std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >'
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_set.h:133:17:   required from 'class std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)>'
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_pair.h:218:11:   required from 'struct std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> >'
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\ext\aligned_buffer.h:56:65:   required from 'struct __gnu_cxx::__aligned_membuf<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> > >'
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_tree.h:231:41:   required from 'struct std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> > >'
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_tree.h:1887:21:   required from 'void std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> > >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> > >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> > >*]'
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_tree.h:984:9:   required from 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::~_Rb_tree() [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> >; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> > >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::set<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)> > >]'
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_map.h:185:7:   required from here
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_tree.h:144:33: error: data member 'std::_Rb_tree_key_compare<bool(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)>::_M_key_compare' invalidly declared function type
  144 |       _Key_compare              _M_key_compare;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_set.h:327:7: error: function returning a function
  327 |       key_comp() const
      |       ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_set.h:331:7: error: function returning a function
  331 |       value_comp() const
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). It looks like you're not using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn c++.

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also **why do you have `int32_t main() `???**

Comment: Pretty sure that `cmp` doesn't respect strict weak ordering.

Comment: "`ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
     cin.tie(nullptr);` - don't do that. You can get into all kinds of trouble if you don't know what you are doing (and you clearly don't).

Comment: `decltype` would leave you with only the type of the `cmp` function. Lets say you have the two functions `int add(int, int)` and `int sub(int, int)`. Both have the same type. If you use `decltype` on it, both would look the same. You should rather write a functor.

Comment: Looks like you are learning C++ from a low quality source. The include statement, using using namespace, lazily using std::pair (which is semantically meaningless and should only be used in template programming) and then some code that's clearly just copied from competitive coding (sync_with_stdio and tie).... What source are you using to learn C++ from?

Comment: Use any of those resources to learn C++ from : a [recent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (make sure it is up-to-date and not teaching you "C"). Or you can use  [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com/). Also make sure to check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to explore what C++ has to offer (containers/algorithms). 
And finally refer to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to learn how C++  is intended to be used.

Comment: Instead of std::pair, declare a struct with two clearly named member variables of your own e.g. `struct your_struct { std::string key; int value; };`. Your compare function then becomes : `bool cmp(const your_struct& aa, const your_struct& bb)` and the compiler can never confuse it with any other string/int pair.

Comment: `main` always returns an `int`, even when `int` is not 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

The crucial mistake can be seen in the error message that GCC gives you:

```
.../stl_tree.h:140:33: error: data member 'std::_Rb_tree_key_compare<bool(...)>::_M_key_compare' invalidly declared function type
  140 |       _Key_compare              _M_key_compare;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`decltype(cmp)` is a function type because `cmp` is a function. You probably wanted `decltype(cmp)*` which would be a function pointer.

However, if you used a function pointer type as a comparison for the `std::map`, you would also need to provide the function pointer each time you make a `std::set` which is to be inserted. That would be quite tedious, and a way around that is to make a new type:

```cpp
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const pair<string, int>& aa, const pair<string, int>& bb) const {
        return (aa.second == bb.second ? aa.first < bb.first : aa.second > bb.second);
    }
};

// ...
map<string, set<pair<string, int>, cmp>> store;
```

Answer (score 2):

`decltype(cmp)` is just `bool(pair<string, int>, pair<string, int>)`.  That is, it's the type "function that returns `bool` and accepts two `pair`s as parameters".  It doesn't carry any information about *which* function.  It's also not a type that can be default-constructed (or constructed at all, for that matter).

To use such a raw function as a set comparator, you have to provide a pointer type as your set's comparator type and also provide a pointer to the function to the set's constructor:

```
std::set<std::pair, int>, decltype(&cmp)> my_set(&cmp);
```

That's not very convenient to do when you have a bunch of sets in a map that may try to default-construct them when looking up non-existent keys.

To avoid needing to pass a pointer to `cmp` to the constructor of every set in your map, it would make more sense to make `cmp` a class with an overloaded `operator()`.  That allows you to encode the information about *which* function to call in type that you pass as `std::set`'s comparator type:

```
struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(std::pair<std::string, int> aa, std::pair<std::string, int> bb) const
    {
        return (aa.second == bb.second ? aa.first < bb.first : aa.second > bb.second);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>, cmp>> store;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecc3c5a54adee374)